# Using AngularJS for Ajax POST in Struts 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, struts

I'm trying to send Ajax POST using Struts action form.

I've succeeded to create this kind of call using jQuery.

**`ActionForm`:**

```java
public class AjaxForm extends ActionForm {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7403728678369985647L;

    private String name = null;
    private FormFile uploadedFile = null;

    
    public FormFile getuploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }
    
    public void setFile(FormFile uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }
    
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**`Action`:**

```java
public class AjaxAction extends Action{


public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {   

    
    AjaxForm ajaxForm = (AjaxForm)form;
    System.out.println("Hello " + ajaxForm.getName());
```

**jQuery Ajax POST (working):**

```jsp
    <script src="/BusinessProcess_Project/jquery.js"></script>
     
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function doAjaxPost() {
            // get the form values
            //var name = $('#name').val();
            
            var formData ={
                    'name':'jQuery_Oron'
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/BusinessProcess_Project/AjaxSubmit.do",
              //  data: "name=" + 'jQuery',
                data:formData,
                dataType: "text/json",
                success: function(response){             
                   
                },
                error: function(e){
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**AngularJS Ajax POST (*not* working):**

```jsp
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $scope.myShabi = {};
        
        $scope.myShabi.doClick = function(item, event) {     
       // $scope.init = function(item, event) {         
            $scope.loading = true;
            
            
            var formData ={
                    'name':'Angular_Oron'
            };
                            
            var responsePromise = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/BusinessProcess_Project/AjaxSubmit.do',
                    data: formData
            });


            responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.jsonFromServer = data;
                 
                $scope.status ="Finished";
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
            
            responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("AJAX failed!");
            });
        };
    </script>
```

for some reason AngularJS doesn't like the way I'm sending the `ActionForm` data.

Comment: What error are you getting ?
BTW, I think you should chain the success and error, to avoid unnecessary lookups.
`var responsePromise = $http(...).success(...).error(...)`

Comment: Hi,thanks for your update, i'm not getting error, just getting: 'Hello null'

Comment: What if you add `responseType: "json"` ?
    var responsePromise = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/BusinessProcess_Project/AjaxSubmit.do',
                    data: formData,
                    responseType: "json"
            });

Comment: still getting "Hello null'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `data` that you should use, but `params` :

```
...
var responsePromise = $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/BusinessProcess_Project/AjaxSubmit.do',
    // data: formData
    params: formData
});
...
```